# rkhunter Apache2 Warning caused by phpmyadmin-Docker-Container

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, spam-prevention, rootkit, whitelist

recently we get the following reports from rkhunter:

```
Warning: The following processes are using suspicious files:
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 11286
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 11396
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 0    PID: 26846
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 27010
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 27689
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28005
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28019
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28110
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28111
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28715
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
     Command: apache2
       UID: 33    PID: 28716
       Pathname: 
       Possible Rootkit: Spam tool component
```

After some tests and google researches we found out that this comes from the official phpmyadmin docker image. The container can't run without apache2 running on the docker host in the foreground.

The question is how you can whitelist this false positives in rkhunter. The PID might change every start, so whitelisting PIDs is not the best solution. Apache2 as a service can't be whitelisted because it isn't running as a service on the host.